# AWS Cognito User Pool with Google Sign In (Google One-Tap)

Tags: amazon-cognito, google-one-tap

I setup a AWS cognito user pool which is enabled to login via a Google. I use aws-hosted login UI. With the Google sign-in, the creation of the user in the cognito userpool is done by AWS. I logged in with my Google user and the user is now present in the userpool (UserID is something like "google_4313213125213").

Being on an android app. I setup [Google One-Tap login](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/overview?hl=de): After the login via Google One-Tap, Google issues a Google ID Token.

Based on the ID Token I would like to create a user in the Cognito user pool (the same thing that happens via Google Login via AWS hosted-UI). Is this possible?

Comment: Did you find answer? I've also opened an feature request for this on amplify-android GitHub. If you can, please contribute https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/issues/2457